# Brideshead Revisited: Prince Rupert’s Horse

Tags: meaning, evelyn-waugh, brideshead-revisited

Hooper, in Evelyn Waugh's *Brideshead Revisited*,

> was no romantic. He had not as a child ridden with Rupert's horse or sat among the camp fires at Xanthus-side; at the age when my eyes were dry to all save poetry – that stoic, red-skin interlude which our schools introduce between the fast-flowing tears of the child and the man – Hooper had wept often, but never for Henry's speech on St Crispin's day, nor for the epitaph at Thermopylae. The history they taught him had had few battles in it but, instead, a profusion of detail about humane legislation and recent industrial change. Gallipoli, Balaclava, Quebec, Lepanto, Bannockburn, Roncevales, and Marathon – these, and the Battle in the West where Arthur fell, and a hundred such names whose trumpet-notes, even now in my sere and lawless state, called to me irresistibly across the intervening years with all the clarity and strength of boyhood, sounded in vain to Hooper.

Is "Rupert’s horse" *[Prince Rupert's Regiment of Horse](https://wiki.bcw-project.org/royalist/horse-regiments/prince-rupert)*, commanded by Prince Rupert of the Rhine, Duke of Cumberland?

And is Charles Ryder's most plausible childhood encounter with Rupert’s horse in Thomas Babington Macaulay's poem
["The Battle of Naseby"](https://www.bartleby.com/246/74.html)?